# Flask and Apache - No errors in log, Always 404

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to get flask working with Apache using mod_wsgi and I've been slamming my head against this for over seven hours now.  It's time to ask for help.

I'm running apache using the httpd docker image.

I started by following the instructions [here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html) to get a wsgi 'hello world' application working and that's working great.  If I open a browser and navigate to `172.17.0.2` I see the pages that live at `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/`

In my httpd.conf I've got the following to show those pages:

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiView
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

That's all default from the docker image.

Then, at `/usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi` I've got the hello world example on the mod_wsgi instructions page.  In my httpd.conf I've got the following

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi

<Directory /usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts>
  <IfVersion < 2.4>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </IfVersion>
  <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      Require all granted
  </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

When I use my browser to navigate to `172.17.0.2/myapp` everything is great.  I see 'hello world' and apache prints the following logs:

```
[Thu Apr 16 02:48:14.678027 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 1275:tid 140646030583552] mod_wsgi (pid=1275): Create interpreter '172.17.0.2|/myapp'.
[Thu Apr 16 02:48:14.713667 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 1275:tid 140646030583552] [client 172.17.0.1:38046] mod_wsgi (pid=1275, process='', application='172.17.0.2|/myapp'): Loading Python script file '/usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi'.
172.17.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2020:02:48:14 +0000] "GET /myapp HTTP/1.1" 200 12
```

Now I try to get my flask app working.  This is where things go wrong.  My wsgi script lives right next to the myapp.wsgi script from above:

```
root@423828dd037e:/# ls -l /usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 278 Apr 16 02:16 myapp.wsgi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  74 Apr 16 02:22 website_api.wsgi
```

The script is dead simple:

```
root@423828dd037e:/# cat /usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/website_api.wsgi
from website_rest_api import app as application
```

I can run the exact same command in a python interpreter, so I know the imports are working correctly.

I have

```
WSGIScriptAlias /api /usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/website_api.wsgi
```

in my httpd.conf file

When I try to navigate to `172.17.0.2/api` I encounter an exercise in total frustration.  The apache logs look like this:

```
[Thu Apr 16 02:52:41.678999 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 1395:tid 140174394627840] mod_wsgi (pid=1395): Create interpreter '172.17.0.2|/api'.
[Thu Apr 16 02:52:41.683555 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 1477:tid 140174539728000] mod_wsgi (pid=1477): Python home /usr.
[Thu Apr 16 02:52:41.683649 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 1477:tid 140174539728000] mod_wsgi (pid=1477): Initializing Python.
[Thu Apr 16 02:52:41.710027 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 1477:tid 140174539728000] mod_wsgi (pid=1477): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Apr 16 02:52:41.714671 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 1395:tid 140174394627840] [client 172.17.0.1:40228] mod_wsgi (pid=1395, process='', application='172.17.0.2|/api'): Loading Python script file '
/usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/website_api.wsgi'.
[Thu Apr 16 02:52:41.736762 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 1477:tid 140174539728000] mod_wsgi (pid=1477): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
172.17.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2020:02:52:41 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 232
```

From these logs, I know that apache knows it's a mod_wsgi thing.  It seems like it loads the script from the correct location, but then I get a 404.  I get this for all of my flask URLs.  I should be able to hit /api, /api/login, /api/logout, /api/projects, /api/tests, but nothing.  Everything is a 404 and there's no other error I can see to help debug.

I know that `from website_rest_api import app as application` imports the correct thing because I can go into a python shell and look at the URL map myself:

```
>>> from website_rest_api import app as application
>>> application.url_map
Map([<Rule '/api/projects' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> projects>,
 <Rule '/api/logout' (POST, OPTIONS) -> logout>,
 <Rule '/api/login' (POST, OPTIONS) -> login>,
 <Rule '/api/tests' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> tests>,
 <Rule '/api' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> hello>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (OPTIONS, HEAD, GET) -> static>])
```

I can print these too so they show up in the apache logs:

```
[Thu Apr 16 04:38:57.162667 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2953:tid 139925743146112] mod_wsgi (pid=2953): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Thu Apr 16 04:38:57.396592 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2864:tid 139925713024768] Map([<Rule '/api/projects' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> projects>,
[Thu Apr 16 04:38:57.396634 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2864:tid 139925713024768]  <Rule '/api/logout' (OPTIONS, POST) -> logout>,
[Thu Apr 16 04:38:57.396642 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2864:tid 139925713024768]  <Rule '/api/login' (OPTIONS, POST) -> login>,
[Thu Apr 16 04:38:57.396649 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2864:tid 139925713024768]  <Rule '/api/tests' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> tests>,
[Thu Apr 16 04:38:57.396657 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2864:tid 139925713024768]  <Rule '/api' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> hello>,
[Thu Apr 16 04:38:57.396666 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2864:tid 139925713024768]  <Rule '/static/<filename>' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> static>])
```

I can also deliberately mess up the import in website_api.wsgi and I see that Apache spits out an error message, so I'm reasonably confident that if the import were wrong it would tell me:

```
[Thu Apr 16 04:34:27.634313 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2743:tid 139796746721024] [remote 172.17.0.1:60664] mod_wsgi (pid=2743, process='website_api', application=''): Loading Python script file '/usr
/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/website_api.wsgi'.
[Thu Apr 16 04:34:27.634956 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2743:tid 139796746721024] [remote 172.17.0.1:60664] mod_wsgi (pid=2743): Failed to exec Python script file '/usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/web
site_api.wsgi'.
[Thu Apr 16 04:34:27.635044 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2743:tid 139796746721024] [remote 172.17.0.1:60664] mod_wsgi (pid=2743): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scr
ipts/website_api.wsgi'.
[Thu Apr 16 04:34:27.644848 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2743:tid 139796746721024] [remote 172.17.0.1:60664] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Apr 16 04:34:27.644905 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2743:tid 139796746721024] [remote 172.17.0.1:60664]   File "/usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/website_api.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
[Thu Apr 16 04:34:27.644917 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2743:tid 139796746721024] [remote 172.17.0.1:60664]     import zarzlefrz
[Thu Apr 16 04:34:27.644943 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2743:tid 139796746721024] [remote 172.17.0.1:60664] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zarzlefrz'
172.17.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2020:04:34:27 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 500 528
```

Even debug level logs don't seem to tell me anything about what's going on:

```
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.766115 2020] [core:debug] [pid 2075:tid 140389386400896] log.c(1571): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: yes (1)
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.766422 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2079:tid 140389386400896] mod_wsgi (pid=2079): Python home /usr.
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.766546 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2079:tid 140389386400896] mod_wsgi (pid=2079): Initializing Python.
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.769139 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2078:tid 140389386400896] mod_wsgi (pid=2078): Python home /usr.
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.769300 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2078:tid 140389386400896] mod_wsgi (pid=2078): Initializing Python.
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.805797 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2077:tid 140389386400896] mod_wsgi (pid=2077): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.806676 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2079:tid 140389386400896] mod_wsgi (pid=2079): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.813314 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2078:tid 140389386400896] mod_wsgi (pid=2078): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.845456 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2079:tid 140389386400896] mod_wsgi (pid=2079): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.847250 2020] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 2079:tid 140389373064960] event.c(2314): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.859225 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2077:tid 140389386400896] mod_wsgi (pid=2077): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.860438 2020] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 2077:tid 140389373064960] event.c(2314): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.862762 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2078:tid 140389386400896] mod_wsgi (pid=2078): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.
[Thu Apr 16 03:53:52.863600 2020] [mpm_event:debug] [pid 2078:tid 140389373064960] event.c(2314): AH02471: start_threads: Using epoll (wakeable)
[Thu Apr 16 03:54:03.057717 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2079:tid 140389235279616] mod_authz_core.c(818): [client 172.17.0.1:41350] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Thu Apr 16 03:54:03.057771 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2079:tid 140389235279616] mod_authz_core.c(818): [client 172.17.0.1:41350] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Thu Apr 16 03:54:03.086984 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2079:tid 140389235279616] mod_wsgi (pid=2079): Create interpreter '172.17.0.2|/api'.
[Thu Apr 16 03:54:03.128584 2020] [wsgi:info] [pid 2079:tid 140389235279616] [client 172.17.0.1:41350] mod_wsgi (pid=2079, process='', application='172.17.0.2|/api'): Loading Python script file '
/usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/website_api.wsgi'.
172.17.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2020:03:54:03 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 232
```

#### My Question:

How the heck am I supposed to debug this further?  Is there some place that's spewing secret flask errors that I can't see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I've figured it out - the secret debugging trick was to walk away for an hour and then come back.  I wish I'd tried that six hours ago.

The flask app has routes like this:

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def hello():                       
    return "Hello World"
```

And the apache configuration looks like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /api /usr/local/apache2/wsgi-scripts/website_api.wsgi
```

That means to see flask print "Hello World", I need to go to `172.17.0.2/api/api` and not `172.17.0.2/api` like I was trying before.

I will need to do some additional work to make the routes match when I'm debugging with flask's built-in server vs production, but that's a different stack overflow question